# Deleting a pointer to a pointer causes "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" error

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, heap-corruption

I was solving a simple math question which needs to add solutions continuouslly to the answer set. So I designed a class with a pointer to a pointer in it. Whenever a new solution is worked out, I define another new temporary pointer to a pointer to hold answer set's data and enlarge the capacity of answer set and re-initialize it. Then copy former data and store new solution to answer set.

While deleting the temporary pointer, the program always crashes into "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" error.
Exactly at deleting the pointer arrays pointed by it.

Removing the corresponding codes makes everything work right. But I guess there will be a memory leak with larger data set because of missing `delete[]`.

I think I had used copy function in a right way and made every unused pointer point to NULL.

So, here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CChickProblem.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        CChickProblem c(a, b);
        c.findSolution();
        c.printSolution();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CChickProblem.h:

```
#pragma once

class CChickProblem
{
private:
    int cockNum, henNum, chickNum, answerNum, totalNum, totalPrice;
    static int singleCockPrice, singleHenPrice, tripleChickPrice, chickenKindNum;
    int **answer;

public:
    CChickProblem(int money, int number);
    ~CChickProblem();
    void findSolution();
    void printSolution();
};
```

CChickProblem.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CChickProblem.h"
using namespace std;

int CChickProblem::singleCockPrice = 5;
int CChickProblem::singleHenPrice = 3;
int CChickProblem::tripleChickPrice = 1;
int CChickProblem::chickenKindNum = 3;

CChickProblem::CChickProblem(int number, int money)
{
    totalNum = number;
    totalPrice = money;
    cockNum = henNum = chickNum = answerNum = 0;
    answer = nullptr;
}

CChickProblem::~CChickProblem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < answerNum; i++)
    {
        delete[] * (answer + i);
    }
    delete[] answer;
}

void CChickProblem::findSolution()
{
    for (cockNum = 0; cockNum <= (totalPrice / singleCockPrice); cockNum++)
    {
        for (henNum = 0; henNum <= (totalPrice / singleHenPrice); henNum++)
        {
            for (chickNum = 0; chickNum <= (totalPrice / tripleChickPrice * 3); chickNum += 3)
            {
                if (cockNum * henNum * chickNum != 0 && cockNum + henNum + chickNum == totalNum && cockNum * singleCockPrice + henNum * singleHenPrice + chickNum / 3 * tripleChickPrice == totalPrice)
                {
                    int **extra = new int *[answerNum];
                    for (int i = 0; i < answerNum; i++)
                    {
                        *(extra + i) = new int[chickenKindNum];
                    }
                    copy(answer, answer + answerNum, extra);
                    answer = new int *[++answerNum];
                    for (int i = 0; i < answerNum; i++)
                    {
                        *(answer + i) = new int[chickenKindNum];
                    }
                    copy(extra, extra + answerNum - 1, answer);
                    if (extra)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < answerNum - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (extra[i])
                            {
                                delete[] extra[i];//Where crashes!!
                                extra[i] = nullptr;
                            }
                        }
                        delete[] extra;
                        extra = nullptr;
                    }
                    *(answer + answerNum - 1) = new int[chickenKindNum];
                    for (int i = 0; i < chickenKindNum; i++)
                    {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            *(*(answer + answerNum - 1) + i) = cockNum;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            *(*(answer + answerNum - 1) + i) = henNum;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            *(*(answer + answerNum - 1) + i) = chickNum;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void CChickProblem::printSolution()
{
    cout << answerNum << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < answerNum; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < chickenKindNum; j++)
        {
            cout << *(*(answer + i) + j);
            if (j != 2)
            {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using `std::vector` to manage your dynamic arrays rather than doing everything manually

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers, `new` and `delete` at all here? Just use appropriate standard container classes (e.g. `std::vector<T>`,`std::array<T, Size>` or `std::list<T>`) as needed, and overcome this caveman memory management style in c++.

Comment: Why all the unreadable (and error-prone) pointer arithmetic when you could be indexing?

Comment: `copy(answer, answer + answerNum, extra)` copies the pointers from `answer` into `extra` overwriting the new pointers you've just allocated. `*(extra + i)` is more simply written as `extra[i]`

Comment: An aside: the loop `for (int i = 0; i < answerNum - 1; i++) ...` appears to be skipping `extra[answerNum-1]`.

Comment: As a c++ beginner, I tried my best to optimize the code.  I never learned these new features above. You guys are right, I should abandon this  efficient-less way.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: It might still be a good debugging exercise to *think* through your code and see if you can figure out how you ended up with the extra or erroneous `delete[]`.

Comment: lurker, you are right. There is an extra `delete []`. I haven't recognized what `delete` really does before using it in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,guys. After days of testing and trying,I figured out where this foolish problem is. The `delete [] extra[i]` in an attempt to delete the pointers is totally unneccessary cause it will remove the pointed data on the heap which is arranged to be reused in the following code without deleting the pointer itself. And, as it has removed data in the heap, when program ends at a destructer,it will find nothing to destruct, thus trigger error.
So the proper way to destruct pointers without deleting the pointed data, is just to  create another pointer to the originally pointed data in case you can't find them and make the original pointer point to NULL.
In my program, it should be like deleting the pointer to a pointer after copy progress.